# Physics2d.IgnoreLayerCollision not working when PlatformEffector2D is used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on a basic platforming game, and my player controller has a system where if S is hit, then the player should ignore collisions with objects in the platform layer. However, Even though run the IgnoreLayerCollision, my player still detects the collisions. Any fixes?

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{

    //Drop through platforms or not?

    if (dropDown)
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 8, true);

        playerCollider.enabled = false;
        platformCollider.enabled = false;
        playerCollider.enabled = true;
        platformCollider.enabled = true;

        print("Dropdown");
    }else
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 8, false);
}

void getInput()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        dropDown = true;

    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
    {
        dropDown = false;

    }

}
```

Dropdown does print properly

[Platform inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as0au.png)

[player inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLqeD.png)

[Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BEr3.png)

[Inspector for platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8LiJ.png)

[Inspector for player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frzNJ.png)

Comment: How do you know that the player is still detecting collisions? You left that part out and it's hard to know how exactly you are detecting the collision

Comment: Im not sure whether or not the player is still detecting collisions, but the player does not fall through the platform, and continues to collide with it.

Comment: *"where if S is hit, then the player should ignore collisions with objects in the platform layer"* When should the collision re-enabled again?

Comment: The collision should be re-enabled after S is released.

Comment: Your last screenshot shows why my last answer was not working You are using `PlatformEffector2D` but didnt mention that. I've decided to add new answer as a whole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FixedUpdate` function is called every fixed framerate frame.  When `dropDown`  is false, `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 8, false);` is called every fixed framerate frame. I do think this is the problem. You need to call this **once** only. Similar thing happens when `dropDown` is true. `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 8, true);` is called every fixed framerate frame but this should only be called once.

Move that code directly to your `getInput` function so that they are called once only. Ofcourse, you can use boolean variables in the `FixedUpdate` function to fix this but that's totally unnecessary.

```
void getInput()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 8, true);

        playerCollider.enabled = false;
        platformCollider.enabled = false;
        playerCollider.enabled = true;
        platformCollider.enabled = true;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 8, false);
    }
}
```

`getInput` must be called from the Update function. Finally, make sure that both objects are set to layer `8` and `9` in the Editor or code. It won't work if they are not set to these layers.

---

**Using `PlatformEffector2D` with `Physics2D`:**

With your new screenshot in your question, `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision` is not currently working because you are using `PlatformEffector2D` on your colliders.

It doesn't work because `PlatformEffector2D` have it's own collider mask settings which is enabled by default and overrides whatever you set to `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision`. You can use `PlatformEffector.colliderMask` to select the layers or **disable** `PlatformEffector2D`'s mask so that you can use `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision`. I suggest disabling `PlatformEffector2D`'s mask as that's because it's more easy to use `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision`.

You can disable `PlatformEffector2D`'s mask by setting `PlatformEffector2D.useColliderMask` to `false`. This must be done for both the player and the platforms `PlatformEffector2D` component.

Just add to the `Start` function:

```
void Start()
{
    PlatformEffector2D playerEffector = playerCollider.GetComponent<PlatformEffector2D>();
    PlatformEffector2D platformEffector = platformCollider.GetComponent<PlatformEffector2D>();

    //Disable PlatformEffector2D
    playerEffector.useColliderMask = false;
    platformEffector.useColliderMask = false;
}
```

Also modified your title to reflect that you are using `PlatformEffector2D`.

Comment: It worked!  (I've only started learning unity a few days ago so I'm not experienced with how things like this work) Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should only use single key method (only use `key-down`) to toggle ignore-collision property of the 2 layers. This is demonstrated in below code, here `layerCube` is for yellow cube and `layerRoof` is for blue roof.

Try adding logs in your code to test your incorrect logic.

[image: roof and cube image]

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour {
    bool ignore = false;
    int layerCube = 0;
    int layerRoof = 8;


    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 8,ForceMode.Impulse);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) {
            ignore = !ignore;
            Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(layerCube, layerRoof, ignore);
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, the below snippets in your code are also completely wrong and should be corrected:

```
playerCollider.enabled = false;
platformCollider.enabled = false;
playerCollider.enabled = true;
platformCollider.enabled = true;
```

the above code effectively is simply setting the colliders to `true`. For what you are trying to achieve, you should simply remove the above lines. These are not at all required if you are already adding code to ignore layer collisions.

Comment: I've removed the unecessary lines, and moved the IgnoreLayerCollision to the input. Still doesn't work, so far.

Comment: *"These are not at all required if you are already adding code to ignore layer collisions."* Yes but in the past, there was an issue that requires disabling and enabling the collider component after `Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision` is called in order to see its effect. So that part of code is not unnecessary as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem with:
change by "Platform Effector 2D" the "Use Collider Mask" to false